# MVC 4: Ambiguous request for action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FolderChange", "EdiSender", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "ediFilesForm"}))
{
    var directoriesSelectList = new SelectList(Model.Directories);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDirectory, directoriesSelectList, new {@Id = "Directories",     
    @style = "width:Auto;", @size = 20, onchange = "$('#ediFilesForm').submit()", name = "action:FolderChange"})

    var ediFilesSelectList = new SelectList(Model.EdiFileNames);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEdiFile, ediFilesSelectList, new {@Id = "EdiFileNames",       
    @style = "width:Auto;", @size = 20})
}
<br/>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="action:Send" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action:Delete" />
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh" name="action:Refresh" />
</form>

Here is a part of the controller:

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("FolderChange")]
    public ActionResult FolderChange(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
    {
        ediFileModel = Load(ediFileModel.SelectedDirectory);
        return View("Index", ediFileModel);
    }
...

    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Send")]
    public ActionResult Send(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
    {
        ....
        return View("Index", ediFileModel);
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
}
```

When I press any of the buttons, I get the following message:

> The current request for action 'FolderChange' on controller type 'EdiSenderController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Send(EdiSimulatorWebSender.Models.EdiFileModel) on type EdiSimulatorWebSender.Controllers.EdiSenderController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult FolderChange(EdiSimulatorWebSender.Models.EdiFileModel) on type EdiSimulatorWebSender.Controllers.EdiSenderController

Could you please help me understand what is wrong with my view?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I added it to my question.

Comment: you have one action with name ``FolderChange``?

Comment: why are you puttin actionmame attribute if both are exactly same,remove this attribute and try: ``[ActionName("FolderChange")]``

Comment: i suspect due to that it is detecting two action with same name

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I have one action with name "FolderChange".
I put this attribute to prevent from looking for a view "FolderChange", as it is the same view.

Comment: give a shot byy removing it

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I removed, but got the same message. It is not about duplicate action method, but about confusing action method FolderChange() (for the dropdown) with action method Send() (from a button).

Answer (score 1):

make sure on your controller you add the post attribute to your post method

```
public ActionResult FolderChange ... for the get

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FolderChange... for the post
```

Comment: Please see my controller added to the question.

Comment: every time I have seen that error it is because there are 2 methods on the controller with the same name.  do you have 2 methods with the name FolderChange?

Comment: No, I do not have two methods.

Comment: @ Matt Bodily It is not about two methods with the same name, but about confusing method FolderChange() with method Send().